# Limit equivalence

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

"Let $f:A\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function and denote $\Bbb{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $\Bbb{p}=(p_1,\dots,p_n)$. Show the following equivalence:  $$\lim_{\Bbb{x}\to\Bbb{p}}f(\Bbb{x})=L\iff\lim_{(h_1,\dots,h_n)\to(0,\dots,0)}f((p_1+h_1,\dots,p_n+h_n))=L"$$
I've understood it intuitively, but how do I write it down using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{\Bbb{x}\to\Bbb{p}}f(\Bbb{x})=L$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\forall\epsilon,\exists\delta:\|x-p\|<\delta , |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
Now rewriting this one with $x=p+h$ 
$$\forall\epsilon,\exists\delta:\|h\|<\delta , |f(p+h)-L|<\epsilon$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\lim_{\Bbb{h}\to\Bbb{0}}f(p+h)=L$$

:)